# Eclipse creating unwanted workspace

Tags: eclipse

Every time I start Eclipse (Mars), it create a Workspace folder on my desktop, despite all preferences in "Startup and Shutdown" and "Launching" being set to a folder in MyDocuments, and no project existing which uses that directory.

I also checked the .ini file to make sure it was not mentioned there, and searched the registry and did not find it.

Why is Eclipse creating this empty Workspace on every startup?